# Mongoose schema for storing an array of JSON objects for subdocuments

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a JSON object that I want to create a schema for using mongoose

```
    { ProjectName: 'asdf',
  Embargo: 'Yes',
  Angle: '1',
  Facts: '[{"count":1,"fact":"dsafdsaf","content":"dsafdsaf"}, {"count":3,"fact":"dsafdsaf","content":"dsafdsaf" } , {"count":2,"fact":"dsafdsaf","content":"dsafdsaf"}]',
  About: '<p>Anthony Bodin&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>',
  EditorNote: 'No',
  OrderId: 'tok_14kGRO2Jju1nvjb47YF9jQTJ',
  Payment: 'Paid' }
```

My problem is that the Facts element will contain and array of objects and I am not quite sure how to save it into the database as 
Here is the schema that I have right now

```
var ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    userEmail: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    article: {
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date()
        },
        ProjectName: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        Embargo: {
            type: String,
            default: true
        },
        Angle: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        Facts: {                
            type:Array
        },
        About: {
            type:String,
            default:''
        },
        EditorNote: {
            type:String,
            default:''
        },  
        Payment: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Not Paid'
        },
        OrderId: {
            type:String,
            default:''
        }
    }
});
```

Is saving the data as an array the right way to save the Facts element ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its very simple. Just make facts an array.
So change

```
Facts: {                
            type:Array
        },
```

to `Facts: []` and it will be able to store the array of objects you have there in the `Facts` json field.